# Is it bad to use conversational tone in the writing of a company website?

Tags: websites, tone

Background: The website in question is for a small tech company called the asyncollective. The general tone of the company is intended to be somewhat natural and non-corporate. I have compiled some excerpts from the text I wrote for the website that demonstrate the writing tone that I'm talking about.

Excerpt from Home: (text enclosed in brackets were originally links)

> We are the asyncollective.
>
> And we're not afraid to break convention, and do things a little differently. In other words, we're not just another tech company!
>
> UNCONVENTIONAL INNOVATION
>
> Everyone likes to call themselves an innovator; but at the asyncollective, we really believe that we can disrupt the tech industry with positive changes and new ways of thinking. Often times, we know what's wrong, and we know how to fix it.
>
> EMPHASIS ON QUALITY
>
> We try to keep everything we make issue free, well-tested, and as polished as it needs to be. We're never pefect, but hey, at least we're trying!
>
> DOCUMENTATION & TRANSPARENCY
>
> We'll publish most of our internal documentation whenever possible, and be transparent about and policies of ours when we can. We have respect for you, the user, so we make sure that you know what we're doing and how we're doing it.
>
> Who?
>
> Ah, we've forgotten to introduce ourselves. The asyncollective is a small tech company comprised of a few people.
>
> You can learn more about the asyncollective leaders and employees [here]. Want to join us in our quest to take over mankind? Visit the [Careers page] for details on how you can work with us.

Excerpt from About Us:

> If the introduction on our home page wasn't enough for you, let's talk about some other cool things about the asyncollective.

It should be pretty clear from these excerpts the general tone of text on this website. Is it too conversational, or is it appropriate for how we want to come across?

Comment: What is the tone of the writing on the websites of your competitors and customers? Write in that tone. —— Never write in a vacuum. Always get to know the context your writing appears in.

Comment: Companies can do almost anything these days. Some people will consider the tone to be annoying and vague, and just want the facts; others may find it amusing or charming. You can't really generalize.

Answer (score 0):

Always consider your audience. Who is going to be reading this? What do you want them to take away from it? From the line "We have respect for you, the user" it sounds like this page is directed at end-users of the software you develop. If the end-users are individuals, or very small enterprises like your own, this conversational style isn't a bad approach if your goal is to seem friendly and approachable for small scale jobs you wouldn't go to a bigger company for.

However I will say that businesses, even small businesses, put a lot of stock in old fashioned professionalism when they decide who to contract with. Keep in mind that this is probably the first impression you're making on them, before they know anything about you as individuals or look at what projects you've worked on. This introduction is how they're going to judge your work ethic and attitude.

So it goes back to considering your audience. Who do you want to read this? What do you want them to take from it? More specifically here, it's: what kind of customer do we want to attract? What do we want these customers to think about us? How can we convey that in our introduction?